# Running an X application from a shell script via systemd timer

Tags: shell-script, systemd

I'm trying to create a systemd (user) timer that opens certain tabs every day at 9PM with `xdg-open`. Here are the files:

**/home/me/.config/systemd/user/test.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Test

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/me/test.sh
```

**/home/me/.config/systemd/user/test.timer**

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Timer
RefuseManualStart=no
RefuseManualStop=no

[Timer]
Persistent=true
OnCalendar=*-*-* 21:00:00

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

**/home/me/test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash


websites=(
    "http://unix.stackexchange.com/"
    "http://stackoverflow.com/"
)

for i in "${websites[@]}"
do
    # works with /usr/bin/firefox
    /usr/bin/xdg-open "$i"
done
```

This doesn't open anything.

When I replace `xdg-open` with `firefox` in the above file, the tabs get opened. However, when I execute `xdg-open "http://unix.stackexchange.com/"` in a terminal it opens a tab in Firefox.

---

```
systemctl --user start test.service 
systemctl --user status test.service
```

prints:

```
● test.service - Test
   Loaded: loaded (/home/me/.config/systemd/user/test.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Jun 29 15:06:59 me-PC systemd[1513]: Started Test.
```

---

How can I make this timer work with `xdg-open`?

Comment: define "works as expected". You mean, it `xdg-open` caused a new tab to be opened in Firefox?

Comment: @MarkStosberg yes! I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often differences between running a script manually and running it via systemd are due differences in the environment.  Before the `xdg-open` call, add the command `env` on it's own line, which dumps the environment.

Now run the test manually and via `systemd`. Look for other variables besides `DISPLAY` that could be causing the difference. By continuing to add environment variables into the `systemd` script, you should be able to find the ones `systemd` needs to make this work.

Your bash code in your test looks fine, but here's a revision that's a bit more idiomatic if you are interested.   `bash` naturally splits on space and URLs don't contain space, so this alternate code works. I've also replaced `do/done` with braces:

```bsh
websites="
    http://unix.stackexchange.com/
    http://stackoverflow.com/"

for i in $websites; {
    # works with /usr/bin/firefox
  /usr/bin/xdg-open "$i"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to just pass all my environment variables into the `systemd` script? I'd like these scripts to work even when I change my system (Different desktop environment etc.), so that I don't have to update these services every time something changes.

Comment: No, because systemd is not run as a child process of your environment, so it doesn't inherit your environment.  Systemd's explicit use of a minimal number of environment variables provides a consistent run time environment.